# Show post custom field from function template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the Avada theme in wordpress. I'm trying to add some post custom fields into the scrollover (shown by mouse hover). I tried to edit the template file that controls the scrollover but without success. I got an error message invalid ">".

I tried to use this code to show the custom field:

```
   <?php echo get_post_meta( $post_id,'the_price',); ?>
```

The Avada function template is as follows:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'avada_render_rollover' ) ) {
function avada_render_rollover( $post_id, $post_permalink = '', $display_woo_price = false, $display_woo_buttons = false, $display_post_categories = 'default', $display_post_title = 'default', $gallery_id = '' ) {
    // Retrieve the permalink if it is not set
    if ( ! $post_permalink ) {
        $post_permalink = get_permalink( $post_id );
    }

    // Check if theme options are used as base or if there is an override for post categories
    if ( 'enable' == $display_post_categories ) {
        $display_post_categories = true;
    } elseif ( 'disable' == $display_post_categories ) {
        $display_post_categories = false;
    } else {
        $display_post_categories = ! Avada()->settings->get( 'cats_image_rollover' );
    }

    // Check if theme options are used as base or if there is an override for post title
    if ( 'enable' == $display_post_title ) {
        $display_post_title = true;
    } elseif ( 'disable' == $display_post_title ) {
        $display_post_title = false;
    } else {
        $display_post_title = ! Avada()->settings->get( 'title_image_rollover' );
    }

    // Set the link on the link icon to a custom url if set in page options
    $icon_permalink = ( fusion_get_page_option( 'link_icon_url', $post_id ) != null ) ? fusion_get_page_option( 'link_icon_url', $post_id ) : $post_permalink;

    if ( '' == fusion_get_page_option( 'image_rollover_icons', $post_id ) || 'default' == fusion_get_page_option( 'image_rollover_icons', $post_id ) ) {
        if( ! Avada()->settings->get( 'link_image_rollover' ) && ! Avada()->settings->get( 'zoom_image_rollover' ) ) { // link + zoom
            $image_rollover_icons = 'linkzoom';
        } elseif( ! Avada()->settings->get( 'link_image_rollover' ) && Avada()->settings->get( 'zoom_image_rollover' ) ) { // link
            $image_rollover_icons = 'link';
        } elseif( Avada()->settings->get( 'link_image_rollover' ) && ! Avada()->settings->get( 'zoom_image_rollover' ) ) { // zoom
            $image_rollover_icons = 'zoom';
        } elseif( Avada()->settings->get( 'link_image_rollover' ) && Avada()->settings->get( 'zoom_image_rollover' ) ) { // link
            $image_rollover_icons = 'no';
        } else {
            $image_rollover_icons = 'linkzoom';
        }
    } else {
        $image_rollover_icons = fusion_get_page_option( 'image_rollover_icons', $post_id );
    }

    // Set the link target to blank if the option is set
    $link_target = ( 'yes' == fusion_get_page_option( 'link_icon_target', $post_id ) || 'yes' == fusion_get_page_option( 'post_links_target', $post_id ) ) ? ' target="_blank"' : '';
    ?>
    <div class="fusion-rollover">
        <div class="fusion-rollover-content">

            <?php if ( 'no' != $image_rollover_icons && 'product' != get_post_type( $post_id ) ) : // Check if rollover icons should be displayed ?>

                <?php if ( 'zoom' != $image_rollover_icons ) : // If set, render the rollover link icon ?>
                    <a class="fusion-rollover-link" href="<?php echo $icon_permalink; ?>"<?php echo $link_target; ?>>Permalink</a>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ( 'link' != $image_rollover_icons ) : // If set, render the rollover zoom icon ?>
                    <?php

                    // Get the image data
                    $full_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), 'full' );

                    if ( ! is_array( $full_image ) ) {
                        $full_image = array();
                        $full_image[0] = '';
                    }

                    // If a video url is set in the post options, use it inside the lightbox
                    if ( fusion_get_page_option( 'video_url', $post_id ) ) {
                        $full_image[0] = fusion_get_page_option( 'video_url', $post_id );
                    }
                    ?>

                    <?php if ( 'linkzoom' == $image_rollover_icons || '' === $image_rollover_icons ) : // If both icons will be shown, add a separator ?>
                        <div class="fusion-rollover-sep"></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if ( $full_image[0] ) : // Render the rollover zoom icon if we have an image ?>
                        <?php
                        // Only show images of the clicked post
                        if ( 'individual' == Avada()->settings->get( 'lightbox_behavior' ) ) {                          
                            $lightbox_content = avada_featured_images_lightbox( $post_id );
                            $data_rel         = sprintf( 'iLightbox[gallery%s]', $post_id );
                        // Show the first image of every post on the archive page
                        } else {
                            $lightbox_content = '';
                            $data_rel         = sprintf( 'iLightbox[gallery%s]', $gallery_id );
                        }
                        ?>
                        <a class="fusion-rollover-gallery" href="<?php echo $full_image[0]; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" data-rel="<?php echo $data_rel; ?>" data-title="<?php echo get_post_field( 'post_title', get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ) ); ?>" data-caption="<?php echo get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ) ); ?>">Gallery</a><?php echo $lightbox_content; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( $display_post_title ) : // Check if we should render the post title on the rollover ?>
                <h4 class="fusion-rollover-title"><a href="<?php echo $icon_permalink; ?>"<?php echo $link_target; ?>><?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ); ?></a></h4>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php

            // Check if we should render the post categories on the rollover
            if ( $display_post_categories ) {

                // Determine the correct taxonomy
                if ( 'post' == get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
                    $post_taxonomy = 'category';
                } elseif ( 'avada_portfolio' == get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
                    $post_taxonomy = 'portfolio_category';
                } elseif ( 'product' == get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
                    $post_taxonomy = 'product_cat';
                }

                echo get_the_term_list( $post_id, $post_taxonomy, '<div class="fusion-rollover-categories">', ', ', '</div>' );
            }
            ?>

            <?php if ( $display_woo_price ) : // Check if we should render the woo product price ?>
                <?php woocommerce_get_template( 'loop/price.php' ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( $display_woo_buttons ) : // Check if we should render the woo "add to cart" and "details" buttons ?>
                <div class="fusion-product-buttons">
                    <?php woocommerce_get_template( 'loop/add-to-cart.php' ); ?>
                    <span class="fusion-rollover-linebreak"></span>
                    <a class="fusion-show-details-button" href="<?php echo post_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Details', 'Avada' ); ?></a>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually to use *$post_id* you need first to declare *global $post*